# Does 韓国車 refer to the Korean Automotive Industry or to Korean cars in general?

Tags: translation

I came across this sentence, だが、韓国車には決定的な弱点がある。

and was wondering if 韓国車 referred to Korean cars, or the automotive industry in Korea.

Jisho says that it refers to the Automotive industry, wondering what the consensus here is.

If it depends on context, let me know.

Comment: Do you mean here: http://www.news-postseven.com/archives/20150802_338497.html?PAGE=2 ?

Comment: Could be, but I believe I was reading it from Asahi Shinbun

Comment: Apparently, the wrong translation in jisho.org is an auto-generated one from Wikipedia's cross-language links?

Answer (score 5):

韓国車 means "Korean cars" and " the automotive industry in Korea" is translated as韓国の自動車産業 in Japanese.